# Rebol code gui working but not clearing fields

Tags: rebol, red

I am trying following code where user enters 2 numbers and on clicking calculate button, answer should be shown. There are also buttons for clearing fields and for exiting.

```
REBOL[]

fields: [f-ht f-wt ans]
reset-fields: does [
    unfocus
    f-ht/text: " "   ; Changing this to "ENTER NUMBER HERE" does not help
    f-wt/text: " "
    focus f-ht
]

oncalc: does [ 
    ans/text: (to integer! f-wt/text) / ((100 * to integer! f-ht/text) * (100 * to integer! f-ht/text))
    show fields
]

lo: layout [
    style tx label 200x24 center
    style fld field 200x24 center
    style btn button 200x24 center

    tx "First Number:" 
    f-ht: fld 
    tx "Second Number:" 
    f-wt: fld 
    btn "Calculate" [oncalc]                   
    ans: tx "Answer"
    btn "Clear" [reset-fields show fields]     ; NOT WORKING- NOTHING HAPPENS
    btn "Exit" escape [unview/only lo]
]
reset-fields
view center-face lo
```

The GUI is showing all right. However, there are following problems:

```
On clear button clicking, nothing is happening.
```

There are no changes on GUI and no errors are being reported. Where is the problem and how can this be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the fields instead of setting to new strings

```
reset-fields: does [
   unfocus
   clear f-ht/text  
   clear f-wt/text
   focus f-ht
]
```

Comment: Why setting of new strings not working? If I have to set new strings, how do I do it?

Comment: Also, how can I change decimal values being shown in the answer?

Comment: Reuse the existing fields with clear, append or insert. You can round your result, if you want to get it prettier.

Comment: try help round in the interpreter

Comment: Yes, I found it. But it is not clear how to round a decimal number to 2 or 3 digits.

Comment: e.g. round/to 5.55555555  0,01